# arcpy.ListDatasets returns an empty list

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I can't seem to get `arcpy.ListDatasets()` to work correctly. My code and output is below. What am I doing wrong?

```
import arcpy
import os

work_path = os.getcwd() + "\\Lesson4_Data"
arcpy.env.workspace = work_path
print(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses())
print(arcpy.ListDatasets())
```

Here is the output

```
[u'Adams.shp', u'Alamosa.shp', u'Arapahoe.shp', u'Archuleta.shp', u'Baca.shp', u'Bent.shp', u'Boulder.shp', u'Broomfield.shp', 
u'Cheyenne.shp', u'ConeJos.shp', u'Costilla.shp', u'Crowley.shp', u'Custer.shp', u'Delta.shp', u'Denver.shp', u'Dolores.shp', u'Douglas.shp', u'Eagle.shp', u'Elbert.shp', u'ElPaso.shp', u'Garfield.shp', u'Gilpin.shp', u'Grand.shp', u'Gunnison.shp', u'Moffat.shp']
[]
```

Comment: What kind of data are you trying to list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following types of data are supported by [ListDataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-functions/listdatasets.htm):

```
Coverage —Only coverages.
Feature —Coverage or geodatabase dataset, depending on the workspace.
GeometricNetwork —Only geometric network datasets.
Mosaic —Only mosaic datasets.
Network —Only network datasets.
ParcelFabric —Only parcel fabric datasets.
Raster —Only raster datasets.
RasterCatalog —Only raster catalog datasets.
Schematic —Only schematic datasets.
Terrain —Only terrain datasets.
Tin —Only TIN datasets.
Topology —Only topology datasets.
All —All datasets in the workspace. This is the default value.
```

It seems non of the above types exist in the folder that you have, this is why it shows empty.